# Can we use Selenium Webdriver or Watir WebDriver to automate Restful API?

Tags: rest, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

Can we use Selenium Webdriver or Watir WebDriver to automate Restful API? 
Is there any tool that we can use to automate Restful API?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably hack a horrible solution, but what you really want is rest-client:

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

It's designed for exactly the set of use cases that you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used REST-Assured to populate test data for Selenium test which was very efficient.
Have a look at the API its simple to use and you can easily automate your Restful API alternatively SOAPUI will be your best bet.
https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how one would use WebDriver for Restful API tests other than creating a UI that WebDriver would use. If that was the approach the tests would be much slower and more complicated than using rest-client.

We use rest-client, and prefer it over SoapUI because we also re-use the same code to set up and tear down Watir-WebDriver tests.

SoapUI works too and will likely deliver tests faster, but there is a lot of value in using rest-client to also keep the UI tests fast and reliable.

When considering load and performance tests, we are considering flood.io, SoapUI/LoadUI, and SOASTA. If we go with flood.io, we would still be using rest-client and re-using the same code for that as well.

Comment: Thanks jason. It's really helpful to me.